# Do While loops and nested if statement

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that randomly generates a number and the user tries to guess the number. The program keeps count of how many tries it took to guess the right number. The issue that I am having is getting past the `while` loop. When I run the program, it doesn't go past the `while` loop until I hit `-1`, in which case it outputs `"Your number is too low"`. I am not real sure where I went wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DoGuessingGame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int number1, userInput; //assign vars
    int tries = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();     
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  //define Random and scanner input 


    System.out.println("Welcome to the Guessing Game!");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");

    number1 = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;

    do
    {
        System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20. Enter -1 if you would like to quit");
        userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        tries++;
    }
    while(userInput != -1);
    {
        if (userInput > 0 && userInput < 21)
        {
            if(userInput == number1)
            {
                System.out.println("That is the correct number");
                tries++;
                System.out.println("The Number of tries: " + tries);
                System.out.println("Game Over.");

            }
            else if(userInput > number1)
            {
                System.out.println("Your number is too high");
                System.out.println("Please try again");
                userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
                tries++;
            }
            else if(userInput < number1);
            {
                System.out.println("Your number is too low");
                System.out.println("Please try again");
                userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
                tries++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The number of tries: " + tries);
}
```

}

Comment: your do .... while loop syntax is incorrect.

Comment: i cant believe that code compiles. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: use while loops over do while loops. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop

Comment: The only thing your do/while loop does is ask for guesses.  It never compares those guesses with anything.

Comment: You must remove the semicolon here as well: `else if(userInput < number1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nesting and placement of braces is confusing.  No wonder you're having problems.

Learn to pay more attention to style and readability.

I did not compile or run your code.  I didn't think too deeply to see if you did this correctly.  But I might do it more like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DoGuessingGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number1, userInput; //assign vars
    int tries = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();     
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  //define Random and scanner input 

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Guessing Game!");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");

    number1 = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;

    do
    {
        System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20. Enter -1 if you would like to quit");
        userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        tries++;
         if (userInput > 0 && userInput < 21) {
            if(userInput == number1) {
                System.out.println("That is the correct number");
                System.out.println("The Number of tries: " + tries);
                System.out.println("Game Over.");
                userInput = -1;
            } else if(userInput > number1) {
                System.out.println("Your number is too high");
                System.out.println("Please try again");
            } else if(userInput < number1) {
                System.out.println("Your number is too low");
                System.out.println("Please try again");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
        }
    } while(userInput != -1);
    System.out.println("The number of tries: " + tries);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i still have a lot of learning to do, but that is exactly what fixed my problem. Thank you all for the quick reply and help.

Answer (score 0):

Your do/while loop is not doing what you **think**.  You have:

```
do {
    System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20. Enter -1 if you would like to quit");
    userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    tries++;
} while(userInput != -1);
```

Code below this point is executing after the do while loop, hence userInput will always be -1 when you reach here!

Comment: Yup, you are exactly right. Thank you for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra pair of braces directly after your `do-while` loop, as well as a semicolon directly after an if-statement which will alter the flow of your program.

```
else if(userInput < number1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your do.... while loop should look like this

```
do
    {
        System.out.println("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20. Enter -1 if you would like to quit");
        userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        tries++;

if (userInput > 0 && userInput < 21)
        {
            if(userInput == number1)
            {
                System.out.println("That is the correct number");
                tries++;
                System.out.println("The Number of tries: " + tries);
                System.out.println("Game Over.");

            }
            else if(userInput > number1)
            {
                System.out.println("Your number is too high");
                System.out.println("Please try again");
                userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
                tries++;
            }
            else if(userInput < number1);
            {
                System.out.println("Your number is too low");
                System.out.println("Please try again");
                userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
                tries++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
        }
    }
    while(userInput != -1);
```